# SQL nested query

Tags: sql

I have a table like below

```
id  name     dependency
-----------------------
1   xxxx     0
2   yyyy     1
3   zzzz     2 
4   aaaaaa   0
5   bbbbbb   4
6   cccccc   5
```

the list goes on. I want to select group of  rows from this table , by giving the name of 0 dependency in where clause of SQL and till it reaches a condition where there is no more dependency. (For ex. rows 1,2, 3 forms a group, and rows 4,5,6 is another group) .please help

Comment: If you really want an answer, you must tell us the database product and version you are using. Whether it is possible using any feature outlined in any of the ISO specifications for the SQL language is far different than whether it is possible in the database product you are using.

Comment: unless im missing something this doesnt really need anything beyond the basics.  if the parameter for name is 'xxxx' she wants rows w/ id 1-3

Comment: Thanks all! I have my need met.

Comment: If someone is interested, Deborah (kind of) accepted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711561/sql-nested-query/5713245#5713245)

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify a product, I'll go with features available in the SQL specification. In this case, I'm using a common-table expression which are supported by many database products including SQL Server 2005+ and Oracle (but not MySQL):

```
With MyDependents As
    (
    Select id, name, 0 As level
    From MyTable
    Where dependency = 0
        And name = 'some value'
    Union All
    Select T.id, T.name, T.Level + 1
    From MyDependents As D
        Join MyTable As T
            On T.id = D.dependency
    )
Select id, name, level
From MyDependents
```

Another solution which does not rely on common-table expressions but does assume a maximum level of depth (in this case two levels below level 0) would something like

```
Select T1.id, T1.name, 0 As level
From MyTable As T1
Where T1.name = 'some value'
Union All
Select T2.id, T2.name, 1 
From MyTable As T1
    Join MyTable As T2
        On T2.Id = T1.Dependency
Where T1.name = 'some value'
Union All
Select T3.id, T3.name, 2
From MyTable As T1
    Join MyTable As T2
        On T2.Id = T1.Dependency
    Join MyTable As T3
        On T3.Id = T2.Dependency
Where T1.name = 'some value'
```

Comment: You might want to use features commonly available in all major SQL dialects rather than advanced features like CTE's even though in the standard. For instance, this wouldn't work in MySQL, probably the most common platform around here.

Comment: @le dorfier - First, as a minor rant, I hate the lone SQL tag for this reason. Second, one could argue that most major SQL dialects *do* support CTEs. Oracle, SQL Server, Informix, DB2, Postgres. There are more that support CTEs at this stage than don't. Still, yes, MySQL is the lone exception. Third, I disagree that MySQL is the most common platform. I would say that SQL Server is more common than MySQL.

Comment: @le dorfier - Still, I added a disclaimer about MySQL.

Comment: You're right, it's a matter of opinion. But I bet if you counted questions here you'd find more about MySQL than the others put together.

Comment: Hi all, I am using ORACLE -Deborah

Comment: @Deborah - Oracle supports common table expressions (although I think you have alias tables with just a space instead of `As`.) and thus the first query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to recursively query your table, for which you will need a Common Table Expression (CTE)

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) explains CTEs very well. They are confusing at first but surprisingly easy to implement.

BTW this is obviously only for SQL Server, I'm not sure how you'd achieve that in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that came to mind.  It can be probably done more directly/succinctly, I'll try to dwell on it a little.

```
SELECT *
FROM table T1
WHERE T1.id >= 
         (SELECT T2.id FROM table T2 WHERE T2.name = '---NAME HERE---')
      AND T1.id <
        (SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM table T3
        WHERE T3.dependency = 0 AND T3.id > T2.id)
```

Comment: you want to select only the group that the name in question belongs to, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you can estimate a max depth, this works out to something like:

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(t4.field1, t3.field1, t2.field1, t1.field1, t.field1),
   COALESCE(t4.field2, t3.field2, t2.field2, t1.field2, t.field2),
   COALESCE(t4.field3, t3.field3, t2.field3, t1.field3, t.field3),
....
FROM table AS t
LEFT JOIN table AS t1 ON t.dependency = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.dependency = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table AS t3 ON t2.dependency = t3.id
LEFT JOIN table AS t4 ON t3.dependency = t4.id
....
```

This is a wild guess just to be different, but I think it's kind of pretty, anyway. And it's at least as portable as any of the others. But I don't want to look to closely; I'd want to use sensible data, start testing, and check for sensible results.

Answer (score 0):

[Hierarchical query](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) will do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM your_table
 START WITH id = :id_of_group_header_row
 CONNECT BY dependency = PRIOR id
```

Query works like this:

**1.** select all rows satisfying `START WITH` condition (this rows are roots now)
**2.** select all rows satisfying `CONNECT BY` condition,
keyword `PRIOR` means this column's value will be taken from the root row
**3.** consider rows selected on step 2 to be roots
**4.** go to step 2 until there are no more rows

Comment: Thanks Alexander. This qry is matching to my need.